# How to extend external framework's d.ts (jQuery) without modifying the original?

Tags: typescript

I am using jQuery and it's definitions from [Definitely Typed collection](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery). I want to extend it with a [Farbtastitc color picker](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/) that ads new methods directly to JQueryStatic, for instance:

```
$.farbtastic(placeholder)
```

I don't want to modify the original `jquery.d.ts` file to add this method, instead I would like to create something like `jquery-extend.d.ts` with the added methods.

Comment: I would say extending framework with arbitrary methods is comfy but unsafe and not good design. In other words JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Daniel, although I agree in principle with that statement, it is the bread and butter of polyfills - so being able to do it is important, just as choosing "when not to" is.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I can imagine the same done with interfaces. But I'm really not an expert.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out that there is nothing preventing me from adding new methods to the original classes, so in the jquery-extend.d.ts I simply declare:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    farbtastic(element : string, callback? : Function) : Farbtastic;
}

interface JQuery {
    farbtastic(element : string, callback? : Function) : void;
}

interface Farbtastic {
    linkTo(callback : Function) : void;
    setColor(color : string) : void;
}
```

Hope this will help someone one day.

Comment: What do you do with this new `d.ts` file for it to be recognized and used?  I have done this but still just get the error that my new properties do not exist.  I've seen a few answer to this general question but none address what to actually do with this file to have it be used.  Do I have to put it in a specific location?

Comment: @WillyC do this at the very top of your .ts file: /// <reference path="../definitions/jquery-extend.d.ts" />